# Dynamic phone number in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'am developing a custom theme for Wordpress and I would like to insert a dynamic phone number at header that could be changed in dashboard.

Is there another way besides the widgets? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try [Making an Options Page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages)

Comment: Apart from hardcoding it? Not really. What you're looking for is a way to give an administrator the ability to change the header phone number at any time from the dashboard. You would need - in this instance - to create a menu/submenu page within the dashboard, then create an option input, save that input, and call it from within your theme. That's about as simple as it gets without making it static.

Comment: I'am studying this functionality. For those looking for a simple solution, use this plugin:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-options-plus/